# SP2013: How can I double check if the results in my webpart with the most viewed documents are correct?

Tags: 2013, search

I have SharePoint 2013 and using a ResultScriptWebPart. This webpart is connected to a source result.

In this source result I have this quury:

Path: http://myCompany.com IsDocument:True

I am sorting on the field "ViewLifeTime" descending. And as last I have checked the setting "Show Ranked results". How can I double check if these items in the webpart are correct? I mean with correct, the first item must be the most viewed document in the whole site collection.

Also I am missing some documents in my webpart from some site with many documents. How can I check if these documents are included in the results but not the most viewed documents?

Is there some page or property with some clicks count?

Comment: I have noticed you don't mark answers to your questions.. There are many unclosed questions from you, please mark the ones which you really think have helped you..

Comment: Hi, I will try to mark the answers. Sometimes the answers didnt work for me and I add some comments.

Comment: Sure, in that case.. If you have solved the question yourself, please add the answer and mark it :)